# Finding if a folder is in copying process on linux

Tags: linux, process, operating-system

**Is there any way to find out if a folder is in a copying process ?**

To be more specific:

I have a folder in a share drive which is copied there by someone else, and I need to use it but, at the moment that I access it (let's admit that I check 
the existence before and it's okay) the copying process may still be on going.

I want to check this from a `bash/python` script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `lsof` - list open files

```
lsof +d /path/to/some/directory
```

Here is an example with a huge copy:

```
mkdir /tmp/big
cd /tmp/big

# Create 1 Gb file
perl -e 'for(1..10000000) { print "x"x100 . "\n" }' > huge

# Start cp process in background, it will take a few seconds
cp -r /tmp/big /tmp/huge &

$ lsof +d /tmp/big
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
cp      4291 felix    3r   REG    8,1 1010000000 2752741 /tmp/big/huge
```

[man lsof](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html)